# Passing/Using non primitive objects between Activities

Tags: android

I need to pass a List of my objects between activities. I do not want to use parcelable or serialize the data each time. I also do not want to save it in a local file or database. That probably leaves me with using static objects.

Lets say I to use ListA between activities Activity1 to Activity2. I ca

Approach1: Create a static ListA in one of those activities and do all my stuff of that static ListA.

Approach2: Create a static list in another class which I use just for storing this List and doing all my stuff on this list. But this means that this stays as long as my process is running and I have to manually set it to null when I do not need it.

Approach3. I am extending the above class to implement it using a static HashMap.
I have two methods one to store the list in a static HashMap using a unique key and another method to retrieve the list and remove it each time data is retrieved so that the List is no longer present in the static HashMap. So we essentially have to pass only the random key generated to store data between activities which I can pass as an extra using Intents.

Will there be any issues when I use any of the above approaches and which will be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider creating an Application object and using it like a singleton to access your data.  I've described the approach here: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-7%E2%80%93Sharing-Data-Between-Activities.  Some people don't seem to like using the Application object in this manner but it makes more sense to me than putting a static object on an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Uggg statics!  Man I wish all developers understood global variables are bad and how they make your program more brittle and your life hell.  We only been talking about how bad they are for 30+ years, but unfortunately no one figures this out until they've utterly hung themselves on them.

First I'll say serializing your data is fast.  There are great tools out there that will serialize your objects quickly that you can use I prefer http://flexjson.sourceforge.net for this.

So if you are just outright opposed to this you can pass this object through the Application by subclassing it, declaring your implementation in your Android Manifest, and each activity has access to the Application instance:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate( Bundle bundle ) {
        MyApplication application = (MyApplication)getApplication();
        Object anInstanceFromAnotherActivity = application.getSomeInput();
    } 
}
```

The downside to this is when your application is reclaimed if the user returns to your application the memory is gone, and you can't get that input you might need of your screen.  Android framework is trying to make you serializing things in the bundles because if it decides to destroy your application you can always rebuild yourself from the bundle.  Now there are short cuts you can take like redirecting people to start over if the Application has been reclaimed, but those depend upon your program and what its doing if they make sense.

That's where using serialization wins out over all other forms of persistence (parcelables, files, databases) because it can be done in one line of code.

Comment: +1 for your first para "Uggg statics!..." anyway lets say I want to stick with statics for now, can you comment on my approach3. I am removing the static object from the map and should not be present anymore. And I do consider about the case that you mentioned about android freeing the memory. I handle that and simply close my activity and users can request the data again. Thank you.

Comment: BTW this solution has a catch..You not only have to extend Activity, you also have to extend other base activities that you are using like `ListActivity`, `PreferenceActivity` etc and have this logic copied there too...

Comment: @havexz there is no catch.  This will work whether you subclass Activity or any other subclass of Activity.  The idea here is that you wouldn't share the set/get code across all activities because what each activity passes is potentially different and hence sharing isn't going to benefit you much.  I think you are thinking of some other problem.  Acitivity.getApplication() method is available to all subclasses of Activity.

Comment: @achie You mean "the I'll create one big untyped dumping ground and stuff that in a global variable" solution? Yea I think it will create a huge big ball of mud for yourself. Now not only are you using global variables inappropriately and creating all sorts of high level dependencies across your entire app (that's what global variables do). You are also removing all hopes of doing any type checking to ensure you know what keys to set when invoking another Activity. You've also given up all hope of ever having anyone from the outside use your Activites through Intents.

Comment: @chubbard my bad...i thought you are saying to extend the Activity for the shared variable but you are extending the Application. So yeah it will work well. You are extending Application is not very clear from the snippet that you showed above. And regarding extending activity, the comment above is valid. You have to copy the code to share object in different flavors of activities that you are using.

Comment: @achie. At least create an interface and have all parameter exchanges implement that interface.  Each concrete subclass can then clearly specify the required/optional arguments you want to pass.  Then you can either stuff that in a static, *shudder*, or set it into the Application object.  <T extends ActivityParam> void Application.setParameter( T param ) and <T extends ActivityParam> T getParameters(). That'll give you back type checking. Still this has  problems, static or not static, when your App is reclaimed, and the user clicks back button into one of your Activites.  Blamo.